# what unit of image width specified in html <img width=xxx>?

Tags: html, image

I am totally fresh to html language. In the image attached in the html, something we need to specify the width of the image by the following tag

```
<img width=350 src='/var/tmp.jpg'/>
```

So what is unit of the width here? I guess it is in pixel? If that's in pixel, does it mean that the size of the image actually relative to the resolution of the display? I open a webpage with a image shown in the width of 350 in different machine with different display of different resolution. I measure of the width of the image shown on the screen, they are the same. So is that any way to I figure out the absolute width of the image in cm or mm (in php)?

Answer (score 13):

pixels.  the answer must be 30 chars long. so I'm typing more.

Comment: Thanks. It it is in pixel. How can I get the width of the image into cm or mm (in php or other language)?

Comment: Jason's answer is more clear than yours, but you are right, just haven't explained the implications related to pixel size.

Comment: You could have used those extra characters for something useful, like a [link to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-img-element.html#the-img-element) ;-)

Comment: @steveax, you're absolutely correct. consider a beer owed to you.

Answer (score 2):

you can't really work out the absolute width/height in the end display. If you are targeting a specific resolution /screen size then you can work backwards.

users can change their screen resolution with ease, so that affects how big/small the final result is. As a rough guide, its 96dpi (dots per inch), while new iphone displays can be over 300dpi.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning [CSS pixels](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) when talking about DPI and image sizing.

Comment: I am trying to convert a page into pdf. But I figure out that the image width shown in the generated pdf is always bigger than it should be while shown in the page. In the page, the image was centralized with the width 350, which occupies about 1/3 of the page width. But after converted to pdf, it occupies almost the whole page. I think I need to scale down the image but I don't know how much in propotion I should scale down before the conversion.

Comment: Hi steveax, I don't have any experience on CSS but read what you post there for CSS pixels. It sounds like to me that the CSS specify the width of the page in px (pixels) too. So if I know the width of the page in px in CSS, we could figure out the ratio of the image width to the page width. Following that, I read the html source and find the width of the page are, says, 1024px, so if the image width is 350px. Then the image occupies 34% of the page, so if I print it as PDF in A4 side, I need to rescale the image to 34% of the PDF page width. Do you think it is correct?