# Why are values in HTML's 'replaced elements' unitless?

Tags: html

A 'replaced element' such as 'img' is often followed by values for width and height representing the original imagesize in pixels - but why are width and height unitless and not in px?

```
<img src="images/meeting.jpg" width="700" height="215" />
```

EDIT after further investigation: Will deleting the values have a negative impact on the loadtime of the image?

Comment: You got an answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176820/how-to-specify-image-size-in-pixels

Comment: Look at the post **bold** 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493348/what-unit-of-image-width-specified-in-html-img-width-xxx' , this may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually it isn't unitless, but the unit is specified in the specs instead of in your code.

According to the [W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img):

> Give the width of the visual content of the element, **in CSS pixels**.

Comment: Now im a little confused by that sentence - does this mean that the width should be adressed inside 'img' with pixels instead of numbers? Or in CSS rather than inside 'img'? Or in both places? Putting width in both 'img' and CSS will follow Google recommandations as far as i understand: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#SpecifyImageDimensions 
I still think the documentation about the "unitless" values and how and where to address them are not clear - but it probably doesnt matter too much, i just wondered why. Thx for the answers

Comment: The unit is `css pixel` and there is only one, so you don't have to specify it in the HTML. You could specify it in CSS which is the preferred place.

Comment: Thats what i have allways done - deleting the HTML values and using percentage width + pixels max-width in CSS. But in the google link i posted above says that it is recommended to keep the HTML-values: "Be sure to set the dimensions on the <img> element itself.." - this is why i start wondering if deleting them will have an impact on loadtime of images

Comment: @jan199674: the sense of this sentence is rendered more explicit by the next one: `Do not set dimensions on an ancestor that is not an immediate parent.` read `on the <img> element` not as `in the html rather than in the css`, but rather `set it on that element (css or html does not matter) but not on an ancestor.`

Comment: Correct me if im wrong:
"Be sure to set the dimensions on the <img> element itself.." - meaning dimensions can be set in HTML or CSS as long as they refer to the <img>

Comment: Conclusion: HTML values for width and height in HTML-tag 'img' can be deleted and have no effect on loadtime as long as dimensions are declared in CSS